# Table headers: uppercase or lowercase, left or center aligned, top or bottom?

Tags: tables, data-tables, readability, typography

I want to know if there's an standard or at least a nice way to stylize table headers?

Uppercase or lowercase?
Left or centered?
Top or bottom?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Alignment can depend on the data you're displaying, and what you want the user to quickly grasp.

#### uppercase or lowercase?

**[Miles Tinker's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_Tinker)** research work (32 years of research!) looked at legibility of upper and lowercase words.

From a research study at NCBI, an abstract that cites Tinker's observations:

[**Letter case and text legibility in normal and low vision**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2016788/)

> Miles Tinker, an authority on legibility and typography said “Lower-case letters have more ‘character’ in terms of variation in shape and the contrasting of ascenders and descenders with short letters. This leads to characteristic word forms that are much easier to read than words in all capitals”

#### Table design:

There's several fairly advanced frameworks out there.

**[Material Design table specs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-specs):** It appears they use Sentence case headers, and right align headers for columns with numerical data. Right aligning the data (regardless of column header) makes sorted comparison easier.

[image]

**[Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/):** Sentence case again, looks like left align standard.

[image]

**[Salesforce Lightning](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/#react-target):** Their headers are in all caps, and it doesn't seem they right align for columns with numeric data.

[image]

**[Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/table.html):** Left aligned, plus background shading in the headers.

[image]

One common observation regardless of framework is that *table headers are almost always distinguishable from the content in some graphical manner*.
This can be accomplished by:

- font weight
- color
- background row color

**Alignment: Don't center align a header with left aligned text. Don't make my eye do more work than it needs to.**

[image]